# C# Parse string by parameters Domain="LESSING",Name="Admin"

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I have string like 
\LESSING\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="LESSING",Name="Admin"
How to convert it to LESSING\Admin using Framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your are sure of the syntax, maybe a regex... although regex is often overused, it seems to fit this time:

```
string input = @"\LESSING\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain=""LESSING"",Name=""Admin""";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"^.*Domain=""([^""]*)"",Name=""([^""]*)"".*$", @"$1\$2");
```